# How does disassembler understand which imported function to call by the corresponding sequence of bytes in binary file?

Tags: x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly, portable-executable, ida

I have a binary file analyzed with IDA where the function calls look like this:

```
.text:0000000180063039       48 FF 15 90 78 11 00        call    cs:__imp_CopyFileW
```

I'm trying to understand how does IDA convert the sequence of bytes `48 FF 15 90 78 11 00` into the call instruction of the specific function. I guess that `48` stands for far call opcode and the last 6 bytes is something like an offset counted by the compiler in a special way.

So what do other 6 bytes actually stand for and how to manually count the needed function offset?

P.S. Please, let me know if any additional information (function offset, segment start address, etc.) is needed to clarify the topic

Comment: *I guess that 48 stands for far call opcode* - Nope, it's a REX prefix with W=1, setting the operand-size to 64-bit.  Check an opcode map like http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html. 
 That's a near memory-indirect call (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) with a RIP-relative addressing mode (loading a new RIP from memory, in the DLL imports table of pointers).  The `cs:` is IDA nonsense, nothing to do with a far call that changes CS as well as RIP.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is an indirect call by a pointer from import address table.

In an executable image (exe or dll), there's a part that contains pointers to all imported functions, called [`IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#import-address-table). The call uses indirect address from that table.

Usually¹ this information is filled on load time, when this module is loaded. The loader uses [`IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-idata-section) to know module names and function names² for pointers in `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT`. So marking the part with pointers as `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT` is optional, as it can be reached via `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT`.

A disassembler can use the same information from `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT` to know the function name for each imported pointer.

(There's an official spec for Portable Executable file format; linked some parts of this answer to it)

---

¹ There can be delay imports (when these pointers resolved later than load time) or bound imports (when these pointers have expected value based on assumption that a specific module is likely to load at specific address), but they don't make much difference.

² If functions are imported by name. They can be imported by ordinal number instead.

Comment: really dissasembler or even loader not use `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT` for resolve function address. the `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT` at all is optional. used `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` and `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA` ( *OriginalFirstThunk* and *FirstThunk*). the `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT` used by loader for temporary change  memory protection - usually this data was in read only memory (*.rdata* section) and loader temporary make this memory writable, before resolve import

Comment: @RbMm, maybe. Anyway it is different ways to reach the same pointers. (And the `call` instruction uses neither, it just calls by the pointer)

Comment: of course check that pointer was inside `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT` (if it exist) say that this is point to some imported function. not more. for get name of function need already use *OriginalFirstThunk* or *FirstThunk* from `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` or `rvaINT` from `ImgDelayDescrV2`

Comment: @RbMm, ok, edited my answer